# Is the closure of a countable metric space countable?

Tags: general-topology

Is the closure of a countable metric space countable?

It is sufficient to show that if X is a countable metric space then the set of all the limit points is countable.

I don't know if it's true, and I can't find it online or come up with a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

A space is closed in itself, so unless your countable metric space is embedded in some other space, the answer is *yes*. If it is embedded in another space, the answer can of course be *no*: the rationals are a countable metric space, but the closure of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$ is all of $\Bbb R$, which is uncountable.